# Google on Mac is Dysfunctional

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I recently got broadband service at my apartment and I am having the weirdest thing, google doesn't work on my mac.

I won't go into all of it, unless asked, but for example if I do a google search and click on one of the results I will get

"Connection was reset by the server while loading.", in firefox.

If I try it in chrome, I can't even get that far. I get "This webpage is not available" Error code: ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED when I go to google.com

There is nothing wrong with my ISP, it works just fine on Fedora under VirtualBox on the same mac.

Now I can't get to youtube.com from any browser on the mac. I get a "The connection was reset" on firefox, ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on chrome, "The server unexpectedly dropped the connection" on safari. It works under any browser in the virtual machine.

If it helps, search results from duckduckgo work just fine.

Edit:
I tried all of the suggestions on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202516 That didn't help, it seems strange to change the command line utilities with every release of osx, but that is an aside.

Edit:
Google Drive works under chrome.

Comment: since  you're having issues wtih multiple browsers getting to youtube.com, I'd look at the network setup as a possible culprit. If you're using wi-fi, try wired. If you can't, make sure your drivers and any timeouts are set high. Also, try creating a new Mac user and see if it happens on that profile as well, thus indicating something specific to your ID. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the 'connection reset' error under different circumstances, but it ultimately resolved to having a 32-bit Flash plugin on a 64-bit system & browser.

Not certain, but it's definitely worth investigating.

Might even be worth grabbing the full distribution installer just to make sure all the right bits get plumbed in - this address moves around periodically but is currently at http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html

I would definitely do a full uninstall first - official Mac uninstaller from Adobe/Macromedia [here](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/support/uninstall_flash_player_osx.dmg)

Googling "Flash distribution installer" will always find the current location, for future reference.

Comment: I removed flash, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: was worth a shot - wish you luck